# Though he slay me

Tags: usage

Is the following sentence grammatical?

> Though he slay me, yet will I trust him.

Is it archaic?

Comment: Archaic, perhaps, but it also makes no sense.  If you are "slain", you are dead, and have no more interest in "trusting" anyone.  There are various possible slang meanings of "slay" but none seem to fit.  Can you provide more context?

Comment: Since it's a bible quote (Job 13:15 King James Version (KJV)), it is certainly archaic. @Andrew, consider the source ;-)

Comment: Please do not ask us to analyze sentences without revealing where they come from. Our [Details, Please meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) has more information about this.

Answer (score 5):

It is archaic: it is a use of the present subjunctive, now obsolete in this construction.

It means

> Even if (it turns out in the end that) he slays me, I will still trust him.